# Quick Edit not allowing me to change Content Type of a file within Document Set

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, document-set, quick-edit

I'm working on developing a new document library for our Team and am very interested in using Document Sets. I setup a simple Document Set with a few different content types, as well as shared columns. Things have been working as expected so far, however, I've noticed that when trying to use "Edit in grid view" I'm not able to change the content type associated with a given file. Is there a reason for this?

I am able to update the content type through the info panel, and can update other cells in grid view, just not the content type.

Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each content type has its own set of fields. **Quick edit(Edit in grid view**) don't have the flexibility to switch fields dynamically based on the selected content type.

So, when you change value of the Content Type field via "**Edit in grid view**", the page will display "**This cell is read-only**" message.
[image]